# org-mode automatically indent after return in plain lists

Tags: org-mode

I would like to create a plain list like this:

```
blablabla

- bla
- bla
- bla
```

But if I just click return, it shows as

```
blablabla

- bla
  - bla
    - bla
```

That is, each time I click return in a list, the next itemized line automatically indents. I have to click backspace twice to make the list well aligned. Help?

Comment: Use `C-RET` insted of `RET` after entering each list item. Or use `TAB` after the initial `-` to reindent it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain the desired behaviour, the proper binding is `M-RET`. It works for lists and headings.

On Windows, `C-RET` adds a new heading of the same level as the one the cursor is on, meaning

```
* heading 1
** heading foo
- item 1 <>
- item 2
** heading bar
* heading 2
```

with `<>` as the cursor.

So in this example, `C-RET` will result in this configuration

```
* heading 1
** sub heading foo
- item 1
- item 2
** <>
** sub heading bar
* heading 2
```

Whereas `M-RET` gives

```
* heading 1
** heading foo
- item 1
- <>
- item 2
** heading bar
* heading 2
```